# Creating Heatmap with just X,Y

Tags: matlab, patch, heatmap

I previously wrote a code that plots x,y coordinates if it enters a specified area. Now I am trying to create a heatmap with the same data, but I am getting super caught up in the syntax of it. I've tried a bunch of different methods: contour, heatmap, patch(which I think I want to use this with Jet). This is the code I've written. The Data structure contains an array of structures with different coordinates for different moving objects during a time period.

```
plot(square_verts(:,1),square_verts(:,2))
hold on
a = [];
b = [];
x=0

for i= 1:size(Data)
    for j= 1:length(Data(i).TrackData)
        strdate = Data(i).TrackData(j).Date;
        x=x+1


        %If the code finds a serial date, it will store the Lat Lon
        if strdate == 736153; %specific date 
            a = [Data(i).TrackData(j).Lat];
            b = [Data(i).TrackData(j).Lon];
            fprintf = 'bingo'
            c=[a b];

            % filter out NaNs
            if sum(isnan(a)) > 0 | sum(isnan(b)) > 0
                continue
            end

            for k = 1:length(grid)
                if ~isempty(polyxpoly(a, b, grid(k).verts(:,1), grid(k).verts(:,2)))
                    plot(grid(k).verts(:,1), grid(k).verts(:,2))

                    grid(k).count = grid(k).count + 1;




                end

            end
            i
            continue

        end


        title ('Date')
        plot(a, b)


    end
end`
```

Comment: Please be more specific on what your question or issue is.

Comment: so you have your data (btw we have no idea what it looks like) and you do some processing and in the end you want to generate a heat map? (and you question is how do I generate this heat map?) can you post a small chunk of your result data as well? (the data that you want to generate a heat map for and a small 5 by 5 sample should be enough).

Comment: Sorry about that. My question is that with just x,y coordinates that I store in a/b am I able to create a heatmap?

Comment: The resulting figure comes out like this http://imgur.com/2vk9XTh

Comment: And the lat/lon saved to the c array look like this http://imgur.com/p5iyL24

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to make a [bivariate histogram](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html)

Comment: I was more or less trying to get an output like this http://imgur.com/w8ONjMv

Something that showed areas of activity in a square area. So taking the plot that I posted and just converting it to look like a heat map. I apologize if I am doing a poor job articulating myself.

Comment: Okay, I sort of get what you are after, one more thing is that a heat map generally have 3 dimensions (your x,y coordinates and also a frequency/magnitude) is this magnitude simply the frequency of your coordinates appearing? or is there another matrix that assigns this value to each coordinate?

Comment: That's actually the problem that I was running into. I wasn't sure if a third dimension was specifically needed.  I do have a 24x31 (HoursxDays[Month]). In it has numbers representing the number of times there were objects moving in that day (occurrences).

Comment: This is what the occurrences Matrix looks like: http://imgur.com/pzwLX4g I want create a chart for specific date that I inputted above in the serial code.

Comment: One of the problems was that my structures not all the same size because the occurrences one has 0s in it. I've been trying to figure out how to delete 0s from a struct so I can have the occurrence numbers line up with the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [pcolor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) or [imagesc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html)

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: i know.. vote up so i reach 50 reputation and i can comment ;)